# adMob Smart Banner in Swift

Tags: swift, admob, screen-orientation, smartbanner

Does anyone have an example of how to implement a Google mobile ads adMob Smart Banner that supports orientation changes in Swift?

I couldn't find it neither on StackOverflow nor on the Google documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Follow the [Official Quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start);
2. With Autolayout, set the Ad view to your preferred size;
3. in your code, before setting the adUnitID etc, set the adSize property to kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait or kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;

Your new "finished example" code would be:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: DFPBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + DFPRequest.sdkVersion())
        bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape
        bannerView.adUnitID = "/6499/example/banner"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.loadRequest(DFPRequest())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start

I hope useful for you!

Best regards.

Comment: I saw all the examples on their docs and they have one for all the banner types in Obj-C but none for Swift unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the example code for Swift in GitHub.

[GoogleAds-Mobile-iOS-Swift](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I can't find an implementation of the Smart Banner in those codes either! There are only Banner, Interstitial and Native. No example seems to show the Smart Banner and how to handle the orientation changes. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of the Smart Banner implementation in the swift demos of AdMob [APIDemo](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/advanced/APIDemo)
Just download the repository and try the demo.
[image: sample vertical]
[image: sample horizontal]

Note that it doesn't resize the banner when rotating the device. You still need to figure out that part.